# What are the icons by the map name on the character select screen?

Tags: overwatch

I've seen one that looks like a couple small boxes, and another that looks like a circular arrow with a lightning bolt in it. I've also seen it on deathcam screens. What symbols are there, and what do they mean?

[image]